# AllenNLP - Support for different languages

Tags: nlp, allennlp

Is there any current support for other languages? For example, Spanish.
If not, is it planned?
Or else, what would be the way to add it?

Comment: Ok. Sad to hear that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about future plans of a product. Please direct any questions about future development to the vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not have support for other languages. A community member was/is in the process of translating our documentation into Chinese. We do not currently have plans to add support for other languages, sorry about that! If you would like to add support for Spanish, for example, feel free to fork the allennlp repo, make the desired changes, and make a PR.